# Get number of views of blog post in Blog Site using Javascript Object Model or Rest API

Tags: rest, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, blog, count

How to get the total **number of views of blog post** in Blog Site using Javascript Object Model or Rest API ?

Blog Post view will be count only one time for one user.

Answer (score 0):

This query in full rest return the data needed:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='IsDocument:1'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

[image]

If you are working on premise you will have to enable the usage reports in SharePoint Server 2013.